# Не отправляется почта на @ukr.net

Tags: email, smtp, spf

Есть проблема с отправкой ответных писем на **email** адреса *@ukr.net* (адрес корректный) с доменной почты.
Правил настройки домена SPF [по инструкции](http://www.vostokit.com/ukrnet_spf/), но результата не дало.

Может быть кто-либо знает, как можно этот вопрос решить?

> From: Mail Delivery System Mailer-Daemon@timeweb.ru
> Subject: Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender
> Date: November 18, 2020 at 12:29:20 AM GMT+3
> To: info@domain.com

> This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

> A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
> recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

> recipient@ukr.net
> host mxs.ukr.net (http://mxs.ukr.net/) [212.42.75.251]
> SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:recipient@ukr.net:
> 550 sender domain SPF exact match mandatory for 92.53.116.15
> Reporting-MTA: dns; smtp.timeweb.ru (http://smtp.timeweb.ru/)

> Action: failed
> Final-Recipient: rfc822;recipient@ukr.net
> Status: 5.0.0
> Remote-MTA: dns; mxs.ukr.net (http://mxs.ukr.net/)
> Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 sender domain SPF exact match mandatory for 92.53.116.15

Comment: Информации для полноценного ответа недостаточно. Укажите какой адрес прописан в заголовке письма, в поле return-path ?

Answer (score 1):

Была похожая проблема с @ukr.net решилась применением SPF настроек (v=spf1 a mx -all) настройкой DKIM + важно что бы почтовый сервер в MX Records был записан и в A Records